# Cakephp 2 find neighbors wrap around

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm using cakephp 2, so luckily the find('neighbors') is still existing.
What I would like however is that it wraps around.

So if I order by id and I select the first id, I would like to have as next the following id record (works) but as previous the highest id record (returns null if you have the first id). And vice versa if you select the highest id, I would like to have the lowest id as next.

Is there a way to achieve this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily grab the next or previous entry yourself if `find('neighbors')` doesn't return a next or previous array. Here's an example implementation:

```
public function view($id) {
    // Find neighboring products by 'id'
    $neighbors = $this->Product->find('neighbors', array(
        'field' => 'id',
        'value' => $id
    ));

    // If the "prev" neighbor returns null, then assign it to the
    // last item in the model as sorted by id.
    if ($neighbors['prev'] === null)
    {
        $neighbors['prev'] = $this->Product->find('first', array(
            'order' => array('Product.id' => 'desc')
        ));
    // If the "next" neighbor returns null, then assign it to the
    // first item in the model as sorted by id.
    } elseif ($neighbors['next'] === null) {
        $neighbors['next'] = $this->Product->find('first', array(
            'order' => array('Product.id' => 'asc')
        ));
    }

    // Set the data to 'neighbors' for use in the view. 
    $this->set('neighbors', $neighbors);
}
```